# Streaming data from C++ program?

Tags: c++, windows, networking, streaming, platform-independent

I want to stream some data from my program for other subscribers (other programs). These programs can use these data as streaming event.

**What I want?**

- How it is done generally?
- Any libraries or papers pointing to technique and pros/cons?
- Security related Ideas?

I will dig more information on my own even if I get a small hint.

Example :

**Program A** : Object A changed  =======> **Program B** : Report Change in Object A

Comment: Do you want to make this work across the network as well or just between processes on the same machine?

Answer (score 2):

Two things are generally used: [sockets/pipes](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_asio.html) which are just your basic byte streams, and [message passing](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/mpi.html) which is a bit more complex, made for parallel use and horizontal scalability.

Comment: Don't forget Boost.Interprocess: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a bit advanced, but have a look at boost::asio
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Best I found:

- Google Protobuf
- Facebook Thrift

Pros:

- Helps with establishing the formats for streaming
- Fast
- Easy to build

Cons:

- List item
- Other top-level design issues (bandwidth control, cancelation) have to go on top.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly it sounds like you're trying to perform inter-process communication, aka IPC.

In the tags to your question you refer to Windows. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link provides a broad list of the IPC options within Windows.

The tag list for your question also says platform-independent. Either a socket based solution or a Pipe based solution will mostly standard across a large number of platforms that you're likely to develop for. You can either use sockets directly or use one of the numerous cross-platform wrappers, eg. [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) and [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_asio.html), to hide some of the detail.

It's not clear from the question whether Program A and Program B are running on the same machine? If not then using sockets is a better approach.